# how to avoid parent css class style for treeview in asp .net?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

I have a tree view like the below in my ASP.Net page.

```
<div style="display:inline-block; height:400px; width:200px; overflow:auto;">
    <asp:TreeView ID="PostCodeTreeView" ImageSet="Arrows" OnTreeNodePopulate="PopulateNode" CssClass="testcss"
        runat="server" OnSelectedNodeChanged="PopulatePostcodes" OnTreeNodeExpanded="PopulatePostcodes" >
        <Nodes>
            <asp:TreeNode SelectAction="SelectExpand" PopulateOnDemand="true" />
        </Nodes>
    </asp:TreeView>
</div>
```

So the problem I am facing is, as the treeview internally uses the table tag, the css style defined for the table in the parent css class is getting applied to this as  well.

Please let me know how can avoid the styles getting applied on the internal table tag of the Tree view.

Thanks
Guru.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is clearly going to be the selector used to style the parent table. If it's being applied because you just have a blanketed set of CSS for the `table` element:

```
table {
}

td {
}

tr {
}
```

then you're going to have to change those styles to be more specific. Maybe the ones you're trying to blanket are in a `div` with an `id` of `content`, so you could do this:

```
#content table {
}

#content td {
}

#content tr {
}
```

Either way, you need to make the blanketed styles more specific.

If the style sheet is getting out of control you might want to learn [Sass](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://sass-lang.com/&ei=5HooUs-ELcXCsATviIHoAw&usg=AFQjCNGj26Uvw2Xaq_ZQbByTuIQsbFtzjA&sig2=Uu0MNdE9BLgorqTFQq4tNA&bvm=bv.51773540,d.cWc).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i don't have access to the existing style sheet, I mean i cant change the existing parent style sheets as these are used in other multiple places.